# Value of $ (a+d)(b+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \begin{align}
> &\text{1) }a + 7b + 3c + 5d = 16 \\
> &\text{2) }8a + 4b + 6c + 2d = -16 \\
> &\text{3) }2a + 6b + 4c + 8d = 16 \\
> &\text{4) }5a + 3b + 7c + d = -16 \\
> \end{align}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Then $(a+d)(b+c)$ equals

(A) -4    (B) 0     (C) 16    (D) -16

Please note that this is a 1 mark MCQ sum.Solving for the linear equations will give you the answer but it will be a lengthy process.There must be some quick succinct step to reach the answer. Please help me out.

Comment: Hint: add equations 2 and 3 first. Repeat with 1 and 4 next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and the fourth give $$6(a+d)+10(b+c)=0$$ 
the second and the third give $$a+b+c+d=0$$